# Batch read file contents into variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a batch script variable. The file only has a guid on the first line.

If I do `type myfile.id` then it prints out the guid. But if I try to set that value to a variable

```
set /p out=<myfile.id
```

or

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (myfile.id) do set out=%%x
```

Then when I `echo %out%` I get

```
■a
```

Comment: If `type myfile.id` works then surely you've tried, `for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type myfile.id') do set "out=%%x"`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got an encoding problem.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type myfile.id') do set id=%%x
```

should work. (`type` "translates" Unicode files "on the fly")

Comment: I got `%%x was unexpected at this time.` Probably because it was not inside a batch script. Replacing `%%` with `%` helped.